# Slide-effect when collapsing an expanded list-object

Tags: android

I've succesfully managed to do a nice slide-down effect when expanding a list-object by using an animation. I am trying to do the reverse thing, a slide-up effect, when collapsing the expanded view, but with no success. Here is my onclicklistener:

```
head.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (child.isShown()) {
                    Slide.slide_up(Kalender.this, child);
                    child.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                } else {
                    child.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    Slide.slide_down(Kalender.this, child);
                }
            }
        });
```

And my Slide-class:

```
public class Slide {

public static void slide_down(Context context, View view) {
    Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.slide_down);
    if (anim != null) {
        anim.reset();
        if (view != null) {
            view.clearAnimation();
            view.startAnimation(anim);
        }
    }
}

public static void slide_up(Context context, View view) {
    Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.slide_up);
    if (anim != null) {
        anim.reset();
        if (view != null) {
            view.clearAnimation();
            view.startAnimation(anim);
        }
    }
}
```

And finally the animations. Slide-down:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:fillAfter="true" >

<scale
    android:duration="200"
    android:fromXScale="1.0"
    android:fromYScale="0.0"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:toXScale="1.0"
    android:toYScale="1.0" />

</set>
```

Slide-up:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:fillAfter="true" >

<scale
    android:duration="200"
    android:fromXScale="1.0"
    android:fromYScale="1.0"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:toXScale="1.0"
    android:toYScale="0.0" />

</set>
```

The only difference is that the slide-down starts at y=0 and goes to y=1, and the slide-up starts at y=1 and goes back to y=0, but this seems to be the wrong way of doing it. How can I make the slide-up work as well? Thanks

Comment: can you please mail me this code??...i want to implement an effect like this....

Comment: well, it's right here, why do I need to mail it?...

Comment: no i meant..how to implement it ...an example always helps..its okay if you dont want to....Thanks anyways

Comment: @jahed are you able to solve the issue

Comment: @Srishti Roy Nope, unfortunately not